# Merging auto-increment table data

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have multiple end-user mySQL dbs with a fairly large amount of data that must be synchronized with a database (also mySQL) populated by an external data feed. End users can add data to their "local" DB, but not to the feed.

The question is how to merge/synchronize the two databases including the foreign keys between the tables of the DBs, without either overwriting the "local" additions or changing the key of the local additions.

Things I've considered include using a csv dump of the feed DB and doing a `LOAD DATA INFILE` with `IGNORE`, and then just comparing the files to see which rows from the feed didn't get written, and write them manually and writing some script to go line by line through the feed DB and create new rows in the local DBs, creating new keys at the same time. However, this seems like it could be very slow, particularly with multiple dbs.

Any thoughts on this? If there was a way to merge these DBs, preserving the keys with a sort of load infile simplicity and speed, that would be ideal.

Comment: Is it a bi-directional update between the feed database and the user databases?  Or just updating the users' databases from the feed database?

Comment: just updating the users' dbs from the feed.

Answer (score 4):

Use a compound primary key.

primary key(id, source_id)

Make each db use a different value for source_id. That way you can copy database contents around without having PK clashes.

Comment: @N.B.-- can you explain a little more about how this works? At this point I am tracking source_id as the ID from the feed-- so the source id in the feed and the source ID in the user DB will match, though the "primary key" id in the user db and feed db will not match.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use GUIDs rather than integer keys, but it may not be practical to make such a significant change.

Assuming that you're just updating the user databases from the central "feed" database, I'd use CSV and `LOAD INFILE`, but load into a staging table within the target database.  You could then replace the keys with new values, and finally insert the rows into the permanent tables.

If you're not dealing with huge data volumes, it could be as simple as finding the difference between the highest ID of the existing data and the lowest ID of the incoming data.  Add this amount to all of the keys in your incoming data, and there should be no collisions.  This would waste some PK values, but that's probably not worth worrying about unless your record count is in the millions.  This assumes that your PKs are integers and sequential.

Comment: thanks Jon, I agree GUIDs is the way to go, but in this case would mean a major re-write of the app.